# How can i exclude one PathGeometry form another one in Direct2d? CombineWithGeometry exclude mode does not work properly on combining PathGeometries

Tags: directx, directx-11, direct2d

I am trying to exclude one bezier curve from another one, but it only makes my lines wider. Here is the code:

```
 ComPtr<ID2D1GeometrySink> pGeometrySink = nullptr;
 ComPtr<ID2D1PathGeometry> pathGeometry;

 DX::ThrowIfFailed(drawingContext->GetD2Factory()->CreatePathGeometry(&pathGeometry));
 DX::ThrowIfFailed(pathGeometry->Open(&pGeometrySink));
 path1->CombineWithGeometry(path2.Get(), D2D1_COMBINE_MODE_EXCLUDE,NULL,NULL, pGeometrySink.Get());
 pGeometrySink->Close();
 return pathGeometry;
```

Is there another way to do it?